# Not responding to insult

Tags: sources-mekorot

Someone told me that one who is insulted but does not respond, has the ability to give berachos to people.

Is there a source to this?

Comment: I assume the source is the Chovos Halevavos who writes that if someone is humiliated and doesnt respond (IIRC) then he gains all of the merits of the one who insulted him, while his sins are transferred to the speaker. Accordingly, he would have naught but merits; certainly an ideal candidate to dispense blessings. Note: I have not seen the Chovos Halevavos inside it is referenced [here](http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/74_61_73.pdf) for example (second column).

Comment: @mevaqesh: Where in the Chovos Halevavos does it say this?

Comment: Found it! Shaar Hachnia ch. 7. Do you want me to copy the lashon?

Comment: There's a cute story on [this webpage](http://abargel.co.il/?CategoryID=330&ArticleID=761) that suggests this.

Comment: ואם מה שספרו עליו שלן יאמר למספר אחי אין מן התימה מה שהצילני הבורא מעשות מה שתלית בי אצל רוב הטובות אשר גמלגי אך התימה סתרו עלי במה שהוא יותר מגונה וגדול מאד ממה שספרת עלי, הרף אחי וחמול על זכיותיך שלא תאבדנה ממך ולא תרגיש כי כבר נאמר על אחד מן החסידים שזכרו אותו לרעה וכיון שהגיעו הדבר שלח למדבר בו כלי מלא מזמרת ארצו וכתב אליו הגיעני ששלחת לי מנחה מזכיותיך וגמלתיך בזה, ואמר אחד כן החסידים הרבה בני אדם יבואו ליום החשבון וכשמראים להם מעשיהם ימצאו בספר זכיותם זכיות שלא עשו אותם ויאמרו לא עשינו אותם ויאמר להם עשה אותם אשר דבר בכם וספר בגנותכם.

Comment: וכן כשיחסרו מספר זכיות המספרים בגנותם יבקשו אותו בעת ההיא ויאמר להם אבדו מכם בעת שדברתם בפלוני ופלוני וכן יש מהם גם כן שימצאו בספר חובותם חובות שלא עשו וכשאומרים לא עשינום יאמר להם נוספו עליכם בעבור פלוני ופלוני שדברתם בם כמו שנאמר (תהלים עט) והשב לשכנינו שבעתים אל חיקם חרפתם אשר חרפוך ה'. ועל זה הזהירנו הכתוב באמרו (דברים כד) זכור את אשר עשה ה' אלהיך למרים בדרך

Comment: The true sign of a person who has returned to God is that he can hear himself insulted and
remain silent. He can endure even the most murderous abuse with patience. Through this he
reduces the blood in the left side of his heart (the seat of the animal soul) and slaughters his evil
inclination. He will be worthy of partaking of the glory of God (6:2). (Likutei Eitzos)

Comment: The essence of teshuva, repentance, is achieved through humility. One has to make oneself
into nothing -- like a wasteland which people trample over. He must pay no attention whatsoever
to opposition or to the contempt with which people may treat him. He should train himself to be
silent and to be able to hear himself insulted without replying. One such as this is worthy of the
name 'wise' and he will attain perfect repentance -- the 'Crown,' which is the summit of the
Sefirot. This is the way to true and enduring glory, the glory of God (6). (Likutei Eitzos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ת"ר עלובין ואינן עולבין שומעין חרפתן** ואינן משיבין עושין מאהבה ושמחין ביסורין עליהן הכתוב אומר ואוהביו כצאת השמש בגבורתו

[:שבת פח](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=88b&format=text)

אמר רבי אילעא *אין העולם מתקיים אלא בשביל מי שבולם את עצמו בשעת מריבה* שנאמר תולה ארץ על בלימה

[חולין פט](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=89&format=text)

[Read Top Left](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_46089_324.pdf#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH)

Comment: That's the obvious talmudic source about the virtue of עלובין ואינן עולבין, but it doesn't answer this question, which is whether such a person is granted some specific merit that makes their blessings come true.